# Showing representation on $C^*$-algebra is equivalent to multiple of identity.

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I'm stuck at the proof of corollary 1 in the text by Arveson (Invitation to $C^*$-algebras):

[image]

(here $\mathcal{A}$ is a $C^*$-subalgebra of $B_0(\mathcal{H})$, the compact operators on the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$).

We have a representation $\mathcal{A} \to B(\mathcal{K})$. If we apply the theorem on $\pi$, shouldn't we get orthogonal subrepresentations $\pi_i:\mathcal{A} \to B(\mathcal{K}_i)$ for some subspace $\mathcal{K}_i \leq \mathcal{K}$? In the proof we have subrepresentations $\mathcal{A} \to B(\mathcal{H}_i)$ where $\mathcal{H}_i\leq \mathcal{H}$. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in the first sentence of the proof for the corollary, is a typo:  $\mathcal A$ should be $\mathcal C(\mathcal H)$ (or $B_0(\mathcal H)$ as you notate it).  This proof fails for arbitrary $C^*$-algebras of compact operators.

Secondly, each $\mathcal H_i$ is a subspace of $\mathcal K$, not a subspace of $\mathcal H$.  I believe the confusing part is just bad notation.

Comment: Thanks! I guess it was indeed the notation that confused me. I do have a follow up question. Don't we need to assume that the representation $\pi$ in the proof of the corollary is non-degenerate to apply the theorem?

Comment: Yes, non-degeneracy is required. The representation $\operatorname{id}\oplus\ 0:\mathcal C(\mathcal H)\to \mathcal B(\mathcal H\oplus\mathcal H)$ is not equivalent to a multiple of $\operatorname{id}$

Comment: Thanks! Helps a lot.